# How to render user profile edit form in block?

Tags: hooks

I want to render fields of user profile edit page  like "User Name ","current Password","email" in a customblock

Comment: Please be more specific, this sounds like a custom form.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest creating a view that displays user content. You should be able to add any fields you want from the user profile to the view. Then add a new display to the view with the 'block' type.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It is a possible solution. Should I rephrase it as a suggestion instead of a question?

Comment: Adding a question in an answer makes it ambiguous and chatty (DA is not a forum). If you think the above suggestion answers the question, rephrase to a declaration ("You need to create a view..."), not a question. If you need clarification from the user (there might be a reason he's not using a block view), post it as a comment to the original question.

Comment: Rewritten. I'll try to remember to be less female next time I want to help someone.

Comment: lol, I don't think it's so much about gender, so much adhering to the format. It does come off as cold, but the point here is to stay focused on topic to get quality Q&A. There's always chat (http://chat.stackexchange.com/) if you want less formal and friendlier style of problem solving.